# What makes the elevator experience so awkward?

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, social

Elevators are some of the most awkward antisocial experiences that we face almost everyday and no one seem to be doing anything about, while it could be revolutionized.

The question is: **What makes the elevator experience so awkward?**

PS:
Breaking it down into list of factors is a **+**
Referencing actual research, experiments, ideas is a **++**

**EDIT:**

In case you perceive this as a none-User Experience related question, consider how interaction design plays a huge role in altering user behavior in many aspects of life, here is an example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SByymar3bds

> "User experience" encompasses all aspects of the end-user's interaction with the company, its services, and its products."
>   - Don Norman

Comment: If you mean waiting for a lift/elevator (or even [Happy Vertical People Transporter](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Happy_Vertical_People_Transporter)) to take you to another floor, then in what way is that awkward? I have never found the process of taking a lift awkward.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a list of social factors that influence how someone feels about a common situation, which is not a UX issue.

Comment: I think if this question can be focused on a specific design issue rather than trying to canvass a range of factors that contribute to what is a social interaction then it will create a more effective Q&A suitable for UXSE. Considering that there are certain physical constraints to the problem space, a suitable question should probably limit itself to what problems can be practically solved.

Comment: Ok i'm not certain @MichaelLai if i can specify the question to more than awkward experience, the way elevators are designed right now do not support the problem which i have addressed, if you have any idea how to narrow this down i would be grateful :)

Comment: As @maxathousand pointed out, the way this question is asked doesn't really relate specifically to elevators... it could be any situation where a group of people are placed in a confined space for an indefinite amount of time without any social norms for dealing with the situation. Whereas if you focused on a specific behavioural question that is focused on people in an elevator (or waiting for an elevator) or a design question that is related to an aspect of the design of an elevator (buttons, display screen, etc.) then I think it would be more appropriate for UXSE. Thanks.

Comment: although i think you have implied an answer in the comment itself as a basis for the flag, it's kind of obvious that we have different views or perceptions of what user experience is, i perceive it being beyond the interface or the button this is the most similar view that i have about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BdtGjoIN4E and it kind of makes me wonder what is UX perceived in this community but then again, it likely to be flagged as too broad. Thanks.

Comment: @UXLabs I see what you're saying, but I think the explanation for "what makes the elevator experience so awkward" is ultimately rooted in sociology, culture, and an individual's interpersonal skill set. It could be argued that all of these contribute to the topic of User Experience in some way, but I think then you start getting close to the sort of existential argument that *everything* is User Experience. We have IPS.SE now which I think might be a better fit for this kind of question. They also have a sandbox where you can post a question for feedback before publishing to the main page.

Comment: @maxathousand i'll give IPS.SE a shot, though it kind of saddens me since i was seeking answers from more of an interaction-design perspective - hence the ideas and experiments part in the question, i'm quite certain i would have found answers that are more rich in this community in that direction, so anyway not to prolong this further i want to thank you for at least giving me a good alternative over a dead end, cheers for that *+1*

Answer (score 2):

**Let's ask some initial questions:**

1. Why is it awkward?
2. Is it always awkward?
3. And if it isn't always awkward what makes one trip awkward and another not?

**Let's observe common scenarios:**

Friendly coworkers, having a conversation, enter the elevator, and there is no one else in the elevator, is the space awkward? No.  This is a clue to what is going on.

A stranger enters and the conversation stops? Why? Does it always happen?
It would stop depending upon the conversation. For instance it would stop:

- If a group of guys are talking about a hot girl, or a group of girls talking about a hot guy and if someone walks in the conversation will pause. If an unknown person of the other gender walks in the conversation will come to a dead halt. This is awkward.
- If the group is talking about something that is work related and confidential the conversation will stop. This makes it awkward for everyone involved.
- If the group is animated about a topic - sports, a movie. The conversation may stop as now others are included in the conversation. Sometimes people continue, not caring that others may be bothered by their conversation and other times the conversation will pause out of consideration.

Why does the conversation stop? I submit it's because the elevator puts us all in one personal space.

And, for the same reason, it's why being in a group of strangers riding an elevator can be somewhat awkward. Notice if you see the same strangers day after day in the elevator it becomes less awkward.

**As a UX Designer what can be done about the following scenarios?**

- Placing a group of strangers in a small space.
- Inserting a stranger
  into a group discussing something that they not inclined to share (or refuse to share).

I don't see any real life solutions to this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Mayo some effort you have placed in the answer, although the one thing i'm not entirely sure about is the last line you've added, your answer is truly valuable to me as it can be a strong start point to go more in depth in this topic.

Comment: The reason i feel the last line is not necessarily true is that imagine going into an elevator that is full of people where it's clear that they don't know each other but they are all laughing or cracking about something, the very least thing you would do is smile or you could laugh or ask what on earth is going on

Comment: If this statement is true, then we have definitely not given the topic enough

Comment: @UXLabs - The topic definitely can use a lot more thought. And the attitude and personalities of all the persons involved definitely play a large part.